Kafka Streams how can I use an existing topic as the changelog for a state store?
Kafka's Streams DSL offers the ability to reuse a repartitioned topic (those created via KStream.repartition) as the changelog for a state store if the topology gets optimized. This means that it's required to repartition as part of the topology, which automatically creates a new topic with infinite retention, deletes are handled by the framework via delete record requests in the background. This is different to normal changelog topics, which use compaction.
However, what if I already have a topic that contains the data exactly as needed and partitioned correctly? How can I use this as the changelog for a state store?
Creating an exact 1:1 copy only to get the optimization doesn't make any sense, in that case I could also just create a dedicated changelog topic for the store.
I already went through the source code and found out how all of this gets wired together. I also created an implementation that uses the Processor API to do what I'm asking for. I then used Testcontainers to verify that it restores correctly. However, I haven't put it into production, and wasn't able to come up with all kinds of test cases that would replicate possible disaster scenarios. Hence, I'm not sure if it would work as expected.
My question more accurately is probably why this functionality isn't exposed by Kafka Streams, and what pitfalls there might be that I'm not seeing.
